# Warning: Task "mochatest" not found

Tags: gruntjs, mocha.js

While running my code by grunt mochaTest I am getting this error:

> Warning: Task "mochaTest" not found. Use --force to continue.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.loadTasks('grunt-mocha-test');
    grunt.loadTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.initConfig({
        mochaTest: {
            test: {
                options: {
                    reporter: 'spec',
                    clearRequireCache: true
                },
                src: ['test/**/*.js']
            },
        },
        watch: {
            scripts: {
                files: ['**/*.js'],
                tasks: ['mochaTest']
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.registerTask('test', ['mochaTest']);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `grunt.loadTasks` to `grunt.loadNpmTasks`.

That should fix your error.

See [Grunt docs](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.loadnpmtasks) for more info.